# Javascript for radio buttons in Adobe LiveCycle

Tags: javascript, radio-button, adobe, livecycle

How can I do the following:
1. I have a table with columns for Yes and No. I wanted a radio button to a cell (one for Yes and another for No) that when I click Yes, No is off and if click No, Yes is off.

1. How can I make the radio buttons work that if I click the radio button (say the Yes button) it is on (similar to #1 above) but if I click it again, it turns off without turning on the other radio button (the No button).

I really would appreciate any help.

Regards,

Comment: Create 2 radio button having the same `name` attribute, unless if you want to use a plugin to make it fancy

Answer (score 0):

In Set up the two (e.g. rbYes & rbNo) buttons.
In the click event for the Yes add:

```
rbNo.rawValue = "";
```

In the click event for the No add:

```
rbYes.rawValue = "";
```

This will turn the buttons on and off as the other one is clicked.

I'll get some code together for the other option of double clicking and update this soon.

Hope it helps.

Steve